# Possible to get name of file attached to stdin in OS X?

Tags: macos, bash

On Linux, one can run `readlink /proc/self/fd/0` or `readlink /dev/fd/0` to get the name of any file or device attached to stdin.

Is this possible on Mac OS?

---

To explain the use case -- I have a script which behaves roughly akin to the following:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' stdin_content ||:
for target; do
  ssh "$target" "$command" < <(printf %s "$stdin_content")
done
```

This has obvious caveats when the content to be read contains literal NUL values (which can't be stored in scalar variables in shell), and with respect to losing position information within the input file; I'm willing to ignore those at the moment, or round-trip the `$stdin` variable through base64 storage if need be.

It would be helpful if I could detect the case where the script's stdin were coming from a regular file, and directly redirect from that file within the loop. `[ -f /dev/fd/0 ]` actually *does* do the right thing in bash on Mac OS, despite `/dev/fd/0` not existing (the `test` builtin is aware of the `/dev/fd` extension), but I'm at a loss for a means to retrieve its name.

Comment: Interesting question, but IMHO a program must not rely on that. None of the UNIX tools is doing so (correct me if I'm wrong) and this is one of the things that makes out their flexibility.

Comment: @EtanReisner, yes, I know that NUL can't be handled, and I explicitly say as much in my question.

Comment: @EtanReisner, likewise, yes, I know that ssh isn't reading from a file, but if I knew if there was a file, and if so what the file *was*, I could make it do so where possible, allowing inputs that wouldn't fit in memory to be handled on occasions when those inputs are coming from a regular file. That's my goal. (Might be _easier_ to just create a temporary file -- would also fix the NUL case -- but that's a much less interesting question).

Comment: @hek2mgl, I wouldn't want to rely on it, merely to optimize when possible. There *is* at least one standard UNIX tool that optimizes in that way: `wc -c` will seek to EOF and ask for FD position when measuring file size and given an FD pointing to a file. (When not given an FD pointing to a file, it does things the expensive way, and actually reads all the bytes... just as I'd do here).

Comment: Yeah, but it is not relying on the file's name. Isn't it? However, we don't need exceed to much on my concerns in order to keep the comment history short. Like I said, the question itself is interesting (for MAC users, not me :) ) and you didn't asked about design considerations....

Comment: @hek2mgl, sure; needing to know the name is an implementation detail. If I could duplicate the FD without having both copies sharing a location pointer, or if I had access to `fseek()` and `ftell()` calls in bash, it would be a completely unnecessary one. Still, point exists that if the name doesn't exist, the current behavior would exist as a fallback.

Comment: @EtanReisner, thanks for the suggested wording -- that is indeed clearer; edited appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `fcntl` function with the (BSD and Mac OS X specific) option `F_GETPATH`:

```
 $ cat stdinname.c
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 int main() {
   char path[80];
   fcntl(0, F_GETPATH, path);
   printf("stdin is `%s`\n", path);
 }
 $ gcc stdinname.c 
 $ ./a.out < stdinname.c 
 stdin is `/Users/eduffy/junk/stdinname.c`
```

The code should include some error checking .. but the gist of it is there.

**Edit**: Missed the `bash` part.  This seems to work .. not as nice as the `/proc/self/...` approach:

```
 lsof -p $$ | awk '{if($4=="0r"){print $9}}'
```

**Edit 2**:  Here's a version that outputs the fields separated by the NULL byte for safer parsing.

```
 lsof -p $$ -F fn0 | awk '-F\0' '{if($1=="f0"){print substr($2,2)}}'
```

Comment: Helpful! If I were going to compile something with C, I'd be tempted to make it a loadable module for the bash interpreter (directly assigning to a variable, rather than writing to stdout and needing to have the user be responsible for reading that content unambiguously -- dealing with filenames with trailing newlines and other corner cases can be a bit perilous in shell), but this very much provides a pointer in the right direction, should there be no natively available equivalent in vendor-packaged tools.

Comment: Ah .. I missed that this was for a bash script.

Comment: Very nice! I probably won't use it, since I don't trust `lsof` output to be unambiguous for non-human consumption (particularly in light of potentially malicious filenames), but this very much answers the question. (The `awk` script here also fails with less-malicious cases, such as names simply containing whitespace).

Comment: Actually, reading the man page for the OS X implementation of `lsof`, NUL-delimited output appears to be available, so an unambiguous form proof against malicious names should be possible. (If you don't want to do the work of throwing that together, I'd be happy to add it as my own answer -- and leaving the check with you, since it's your work that provided appropriate guidance).

Comment: Okay that version is up .. it's kind of weird.  You tell `lsof` the list of fields you want to see; `f` = descriptor, `n` for name, and it prefixes each field with  that key.  That's why `$1` is "f0", and the first character is removed from $2.