# Figure out number of bytes in input buffer

Tags: c, stdin, io-redirection

I am trying to write a program that reads from stdin, where a file is being redirected to stdin.

For example, my program is called scan, so the call on the command line will be:

```
./scan < file.txt
```

I want to allocate one big memory block for it, pointed to by a `char*`. I can't just take the file name as input, since it is a requirement that I have to deal with. I was wondering if it is possible to figure out the number of bytes sitting in the input buffer, so that I can do a bulk read of stdin all in one go.

So something like

```c
char* read_all_stdin()
{
    size_t amt = num_of_bytes_in_stdin(); //how do this?
    char* file = (char*) malloc(amt+1);
    fread(file,1,amt,stdin); //idk if this is allowed either
    file[amt] = '\0';
    return file;
}
```

Comment: Don't bother trying to pre-determine how much space you need.  Read one char at a time and grow the buffer as needed.  An example can be seen at https://github.com/wrp/examples/blob/main/c/dynamic-array.c

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Your GitHub provides tons of good example(e.g. `(a->start < a->end) ? *a->start++ : EOF`)!

Comment: @WilliamPursell reading byte-by-byte is the worst way to read. It's very slow. [People have managed to pipe data far faster than even the normal buffered method](https://mazzo.li/posts/fast-pipes.html)

Comment: @phuclv Indeed, actually reading one byte at a time is very slow.  Fortunately, `getchar` and `fread` abstract the actual system call away, and do not read one byte at a time.  Using `getchar` is usually quite efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is redirected from file then in Linux you can [get the name of that file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1734243/995714) by reading `/proc/self/fd/0` or `/dev/fd/0`

```
char filename[BUFSIZE];
int sz = readlink("/proc/self/fd/0", filename, BUFSIZE - 1);
filename[sz] = 0;
puts(filename);
```

On AIX you can read [`/proc/<PID>/fd/0`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/497511/44425) instead

On Windows you'll need to use [`GetFinalPathNameByHandle()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29361216/995714) like this

```
GetFinalPathNameByHandle(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), chPath, MAX_PATH, 0)
```

On BSD and macOS you'll use [`fcntl` with `F_GETPATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29926627/995714)

```
#include <fcntl.h>

char filename[BUFSIZE];
fcntl(0, F_GETPATH, filename);
puts(filename);
```

It may not be possible in other platforms

If stdin is a pipe then obviously you can't know the size because the OS doesn't wait for the writing process to pump all of its data into the pipe before passing data to the consuming process

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if it is possible to figure out the number of bytes sitting in the input buffer, so that I can do a bulk read of stdin all in one go.

If you could determine the number of bytes in the input buffer, then it'd create an unavoidable race condition - new bytes/characters can be added to the input buffer after you've determined how many bytes there are but before you've used that value for anything.

The consequence of the unavoidable race condition is "No, in practice it is not possible to ensure that you can do a bulk read of stdin all in one go".

One alternative would be increase (double?) the size of the allocated memory whenever "fread()" says it filled the previously allocated memory and retry (e.g. using a loop and `realloc()`) until `fread()` couldn't fill the allocated memory. However, `fread()` is blocking (if you ask for 1024 bytes and there's only 10 bytes it will wait for the other 1014 bytes to arrive) so you'd have to fix that by changing `stdin` to non-blocking. Sadly this is platform specific (e.g. something like `flags = fcntl(0, F_GETFL, 0); flags |= O_NONBLOCK; fcntl(0, F_SETFL, val);` may work on Linux but not on Windows), so you end up with a a big complicated mess.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> size_t amt = num_of_bytes_in_stdin(); //how do this?
> ```

You could maybe mess around with [`setvbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf), but AFAIK you can't. Stdin might not be buffered. The stream might contain more than one buffer full. Someone else might have changed how it's buffered. [More might have been added between your checking, allocating, and reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#In_software).

The fundamental nature of I/O is you cannot know what or how much you're going to get.

Instead, allocate a single large buffer to read from, probably `BUFSIZ`. Reuse that buffer to read from the stream. Then copy from that to more appropriately sized memory.